# How can I duplicate an event on Microsoft Outlook on iPad?

Tags: ipad, ms-office, calendar, ipados

How can I duplicate an event on the Microsoft Outlook app for iPad?

Event ~= calendar entry in Outlook.

Comment: What does "event" mean in this context (an example would be helpful)? What you are trying to accomplish by duplicating an event?

Comment: @jaume Event ~= calendar entry in Outlook. I'm going to schedule an event that is similar to a past event, so I'd like to duplicate it.